# Why it shows error here? Bad argument type. Starting with v5, only the "Object" form is allowed when calling query related functions

Tags: reactjs, node.js, react-query, tanstackreact-query

Unexpected Application Error!
Bad argument type. Starting with v5, only the "Object" form is allowed when calling query related functions. Please use the error stack to find the culprit call. More info here: https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/guides/migrating-to-v5#supports-a-single-signature-one-object

import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";

const AllUsers = () => {

```
const {data: users = [], refetch} = useQuery(['users'], async() => {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/users')
    return res.json();
   })


return (
    <div>
        {users.length}
    </div>
);
```

};

export default AllUsers;

Comment: It's just as the error says. You're calling `useQuery` with a v4 supported signature. Have you visited the site it recommends? You can also just look at https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/quick-start

Comment: thanks a lot. I am in a learning phase. I did not get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to send parameter in an object format. Example:

```
    const {data: users = [], refetch} = useQuery({queryKey:['users'], queryFn: async() => {
        const res = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/users')
        return res.json();
       })
    
    
    return (
        <div>
            {users.length}  
        </div>
    );
```

Answer (score -2):

*// I have this problem; The solution to this problem;*

```
const { data: users = [], refetch } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["users"],
    queryFn: async () => {
      const res = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/users");
      return res.json();
    },   });

  return <div>{users.length} </div>;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).